# Ruby transform string to method name

Tags: ruby

To test image urls in a ruby project I can call a function as follows

```
validate_url("some_valid_url", "valid")
validate_url("inv#alid-url", "invalid")
```

The function looks like this:

```
def validate_url(image_url, state)
    assert state === 'valid' ? new_product(image_url).valid? : new_product(image_url).invalid?,
       "#{image_url} should always be " + state.upcase
end
```

is there a way to rewrite the line:

```
assert state === 'valid' ? new_product(image_url).valid? : new_product(image_url).invalid?
```

to something like

```
assert new_product(image_url).state.What-To-Do-Here?
```

which would then be equals to the following if `state` contains the string `"valid"`

```
assert new_product(image_url).valid?
```

Comment: can the `new_product(image_url)` return a state already? not sure I understood correctly: you method should return `valid` if URL is valid or "#{image_url} should always be " + state.upcase if it's invalid? - state being the argument that determining the validation of the URL?

Comment: I'd create a method that returns a boolean value instead of a string one `valid_url?(image_url)`.

Comment: This seems weird to me. You already have validation methods, you already know which one to call, what's gained here?

Comment: @DaveNewton the gain is to not use the unnecessary `if..else`

Comment: In the code that calls this function you already have all the information needed--and you only need one of the "valid?"/"invalid?" methods becaise you can negate either's value.

Comment: @DaveNewton now I see what you mean! Thank you, that's a good point!

Comment: "the gain is to not use the unnecessary if..else" - to replace it with ungreppable dynamic method call in runtime is hardly the answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do....

```
assert new_product(image_url).send(state + '?'), "#{image_url} should always be #{state.upcase}"
```

It would be prudent to ensure that `state` can only contain "valid" or "invalid"

Comment: Thank you @Steve, after I figured out the 2 typos it did work :-)

Comment: There's no need to use `send` here. `public_send` should be enough.